# Different values in SELECT with the same OPTIONS (selectpicker)

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

I Have two SELECTS (with bootstrap-select) with the same values (e.g. GREEN, YELLOW, BLUE, WHITE). But I don't want select the same values on the both SELECTS. If I have 'BLUE' on the first one, when I choose BLUE on the second, the first should change to default "*--please make your choice--*" value.
Can somebody help me?
Tks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [mcve]. For further information, please see [ask], and take the [tour] :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by simply writing an [onChange](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) event like this

```js
function myFunction(el,el2) {
    if($("#"+el).val() == $("#"+el2).val()){
      $("#"+el).prop('selectedIndex', 0)
    };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mySelect1" onchange="myFunction('mySelect2','mySelect1')">
  <option value="">--Select--
  <option value="BMW">GREEN
  <option value="YELLOW">YELLOW
  <option value="BLUE">BLUE
  <option value="WHITE">WHITE
</select>

<select id="mySelect2" onchange="myFunction('mySelect1','mySelect2')">
   <option value="">--Select--
  <option value="BMW">GREEN
  <option value="YELLOW">YELLOW
  <option value="BLUE">BLUE
  <option value="WHITE">WHITE
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I apreciatte your attention.

But it doesn't work in my especific problem.

The question is that I am using BOOTSTRAP-SELECT class. Please look that (https://jsfiddle.net/WRobynson/v78o696j/11/) to understand.

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<script>
function myFunction(el,el2) {
    if($("#"+el).val() == $("#"+el2).val()){
      $("#"+el).prop('selectedIndex', 0)
    };
}
</script>

<!-- HERE WORKS --><br>

 <select id="mySelect1" onchange="myFunction('mySelect2','mySelect1')">
  <option value="">--Select--
  <option value="BMW">GREEN
  <option value="YELLOW">YELLOW
  <option value="BLUE">BLUE
  <option value="WHITE">WHITE
</select>

<select id="mySelect2" onchange="myFunction('mySelect1','mySelect2')">
   <option value="">--Select--
  <option value="BMW">GREEN
  <option value="YELLOW">YELLOW
  <option value="BLUE">BLUE
  <option value="WHITE">WHITE
</select><br><br>


<!-- BUT HERE DOESN'T WORK -->


  <select id='mySelect3' class='selectpicker'  onChange="myFunction('mySelect4','mySelect3')">

   <option value="">--Select--
    <option value="BMW">GREEN
    <option value="YELLOW">YELLOW
    <option value="BLUE">BLUE
    <option value="WHITE">WHITE
    </select>


        <select id="mySelect4" class='selectpicker' onchange="myFunction('mySelect3','mySelect4')">

     <option value="">--Select--
  <option value="BMW">GREEN
  <option value="YELLOW">YELLOW
  <option value="BLUE">BLUE
  <option value="WHITE">WHITE

  </select>
```

Tks.